# How to redirect customer from controller not observer to login page magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I want to redirect customer to login page in my controller without using observer.
here is my code

```
 protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\EvaluationFactory $EvaluationFactory,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\Evaluation $eval,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\ResourceModel\Evaluation\Collection $evaluationCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->EvaluationFactory = $EvaluationFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_evaluation =$eval;
        $this->_evaluationCollection = $evaluationCollection;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->urlInterface = $url;


    }



        // Create login URL
        $login_url = $this->urlInterface
            ->getUrl('customer/account/login');

                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($login_url);
 $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

but as result i have no redirection response please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be looking like something below, your controller is missing the `execute()` method which is the entry point for the controller action in Magento 2 and `return` statement which returns the redirection url. Your code should look like something below:

```
<?php

namespace YourNameSpace;

class YourClassName{

    protected $urlInterface;

    public function __construct(

        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\EvaluationFactory $EvaluationFactory,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\Evaluation $eval,
        \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\ResourceModel\Evaluation\Collection $evaluationCollection,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result)
    {
        parent::__construct(
            $context
        );
        $this->EvaluationFactory = $EvaluationFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->resultRedirect = $result;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->_evaluation =$eval;
        $this->_evaluationCollection = $evaluationCollection;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->urlInterface = $url;


    }


    public function execute()
    {
        // Create login URL
        $login_url = $this->urlInterface
            ->getUrl('customer/account/login');
     return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath($login_url);

    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('customer/account/login');
```

You need to return the `ResultRedirect` object inside your `execute()` method

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
<?php
namespace Venor\Module\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
   public function __construct(

    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
    \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\EvaluationFactory $EvaluationFactory,
    \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\Evaluation $eval,
    \Magenticians\Evaluation\Model\ResourceModel\Evaluation\Collection $evaluationCollection,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $http

    )
{
    parent::__construct(
        $context
    );
    $this->EvaluationFactory = $EvaluationFactory;
    $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->resultRedirect = $result;
    $this->_resource = $resource;
    $this->_evaluation =$eval;
    $this->_evaluationCollection = $evaluationCollection;
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
    $this->urlInterface = $url;
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    $this->_http = $http;


}

public function execute(){

     $login_url = $this->urlInterface->getUrl('customer/account/login');
     $this->_http->setRedirect($login_url, 301);
     $pageFactory = $this->_pageFactory->create();
     return $pageFactory;
}

}
```

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setRedirect() on null in /var/www/html/sajjada/app/code/Magenticians/Evaluation/Controller/Index/Index.php:123

Comment: did you do use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface; in top and Http $http, in construnction and $this->_http = $http;

Comment: sorry i forget to add  $this->_http = $http;  but even added this line there is no redirection to login page but error is gone so what s the problem can you please help me

Comment: Check post now i have updated code using your code in my answer use as it is

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirection from  **execute()**, in your code . You did not build Action class properly.

And your code it is missing  this function.

```
public function execute()
{

 return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('customer/account/login');
}
```